# Replacing top poly exercises because of herniated discs

Tags: exercise, bodybuilding, hernia

I have herniated discs at the bottom of my back.

I can't do OHP, or even horizontal unilateral dumbells rowing from now. I can't do kettlebell flexion of my top body for side abs for example. I think I can't do farmer walk.

By what could I replace these exercises?  For bodybuilding.

Do you know a curated list of what is allowed to do when we have such an hernia? Note that it doesn't hurt but my left foot's fingers can't move towards me (this problem will last all my life).

Comment: What did your physical therapist/doctor say? The question is legitimate, but I am curious, was this injury the result of ignoring the advice to get a good beginner program and follow it?